# saving back to drafts using javamail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am using javamail in my app to read / send mails. I want to save  a mail opened from Drafts back to drafts .Is it possible to edit the message and save it back. I am currently doing append which save it as a new mail.What is the right way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change a message in the folder.  You have to add a new message and delete the old message.

Comment: yeah now i am doing that. I wanted to confirm thats the only way. For exchange mails we can edit the draft mails. I guess not for imap or pop .